# Remove near-identical strings (noun plural forms) from list

Tags: java

I'm trying to identify and remove plural forms of a noun in a list. Essentially, I want the below test to pass:

```
@Test
public void testRemoveNounPlurals(){
    List<String> listWithDups = List.of("friend", "friends", "dog", "dogs", "serious");

    List<String> filteredList = removeDuplicates(listWithDups); // testing this method

    org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(filteredList)
            .hasSize(3)
            .containsOnly("friend", "dog", "serious");
}
```

The no-quite-there implementation:

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> list) {

    List<String> maybePlurals = list.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.endsWith("s"))
            .collect(toList()); // friends, dogs, serious

    return list.stream()
             // correctly removes friends and dogs, should keep 'serious'
            .filter( word -> maybePlurals.contains(word.concat("s"))) 
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution adds an "s" to each word and checks if it exists and if so removes it

```
public static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> list) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.addAll(list);

    for (String word : list) {
        String words = word + "s";
        result.remove(words);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I guess some optimisation could be done by adding

```
if (word.endsWith("s")) {
     continue;
}
```

first in the `for` loop

Comment: Thanks. Just couldn't get myself unstuck from such a simple task. For anyone interested the for loop can be written with `list.stream().filter(word -> !word.endsWith("s")).map(word -> word + "s").forEach(result::remove);`